# Difference in Case Created Date in UI and System Backend

Tags: workflow, datetime, timezone, ui, createddate

created date on case UI is displaying 5/9/2018 date but in backend created date is showing value 6/9/2018 When I  am querying through developer console. I have one workflow rule to calculate Target date depending on Created Date. Since in backend created date is 6/9/2018, target value is getting calculated incorrectly. Dates are working correctly if created before 6 pm but we are facing discrepency in created date if cases are created after 6 pm. Created Date is coming as next days date.

Example of Case after 6 PM.
[image]
select createdDate from Case where id='5001h000002br24'
2018-09-06T04:04:08.000+0000

Workflow rule to calculate Target_Date depends on Created Date. So, It is also populating incorrect value.
[image]

Case created before 6 PM.
[image]
select createdDate from Case where id='5001h000002br6G'
2018-09-06T07:30:11.000+0000

Any help will be appreciated since many users are getting affected due to it.Target date depends on created date . How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was just that while displaying the information in the UI, Salesforce converts the date value to the timezone in which the user profile is configured.

So if the user profile is set to some GMT value, Salesforce automatically adjusts the time that is displayed in the datetime field for that particular timezone.

Reference:- https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2014/10/30/datetime-field-and-time-zone-settings/

For e.g:- I have time zone as **GMT+01:00 British summer Time** (Europe/London)

When I am querying the record it gives Created date as **2018-09-07T05:39:54.000+0000** while on UI I have **07/09/2018 06:39**.

Hope it helps you.